# Hololens - Green Screen at Startup

Tags: hololens

I have the following problem: After i shutdown or restart my HoloLens device, sometimes it happens that it starts with the inital **"Hello"** and then Shows a **green screen**.

No restart etc. worked then. The only solution is to use the **"Windows device recovery tool"** to reset the device to factory setting and do the initial configuration (WLAN, Language, Username etc.) again.

After the initial configuration was sucessfull the device worked normally, but after some restarts the green screen crash occurs again.

Does anyone have a similar problem or a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely that you have a defective device, I would reach out to MS and see about getting a replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have contactet Microsoft and: Yes it seems to be defect, but the response was very sobering: "[...]Unfortunately, due to this device not being under warranty we will not be able to replace this device. Regretfully, the only option we have to provide would be to purchase a new device. [...]". The device was less than one year old and well maintained, but there is really 0% warranty from microsoft.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, it is not the experience you would hope to receive from Microsoft when they want us to adopt their technology. I bet if you complained, loudly and (politely) in some of the public venues, Twitter, FB, etc, you might get more traction.